# Can I npm install dependencies and devDependencies from the CLI at the *same time*?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

Imagine I have a newly initialized `package.json` file that contains *no* dependencies or devDependencies listed:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Is there a way I can install both a dependency *and* a devDependency *at the same time* with a *single CLI command*?

If I do `npm i -D react` this will install React as a devDependency.

If I do `npm i express` this will install Express as a dependency.

How can I combine both commands into one?

Comment: You can't, unless you count `npm i -D react && npm i express` as one command.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I figured. Yea, I was trying to see if there was a native `npm` way to do it. Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Why in the first place you want to have a library listed in both dependency and devDependency?

Comment: @OlimSaidov Who said anything about listing libraries in both dependency and devDependency? That's not what I'm doing here.

Comment: @OlimSaidov front end libraries are devDependencies because they get bundled together. Express is a dependency because when the app is deployed, the server will spin up using Express.

Answer (score 0):

Here I install tailwindcss as devDependecies and tailwindcss-react-native as
dependecies for react native project

> npm i -D tailwindcss && npm i tailwindcss-react-native

using yarn

> yarn add express socket.io && yarn add -D nodemon